# My Discord music bot written in python won't play music

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

This is my code, the play command does not throw any errors. It appears the play command works but no music is played while in the voice channel with the bot.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import yt_dlp as youtube_dl

# Define the intents your bot needs

import os
try:
    import nacl
except ImportError:
    try:
        if os.name == 'nt':
            os.system("py -m pip install pynacl")
        else:
            os.system("python3 -m install pynacl")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error:", e)
        exit()

# Initialize the bot
bot = Bot(command_prefix='!', intents = discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name}')

@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    voice_client = await channel.connect()

@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, url):
    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
        url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
        print(f'Playing {url} - {url2}')

    voice_client = ctx.voice_client
    voice_client.stop()
    voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url2, executable="C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe"))
```

This is the only piece of information my bot gives me that may indicate a problem but not sure what this is. FFMpeg is installed, correct permissions applied to the folder and discord bot, I've even directly pointed ffmpeg in the code. I've googled and tried everything but not sure what else to try.

INFO     discord.player ffmpeg process 7568 successfully terminated with return code of 4294967274.

Comment: what intents are you using?

Comment: I'm using intents.all

Comment: did you install discord.py[voice]?